# NestJS $ Print (JQuery $)

Tags: nestjs

I am trying to print *{studentId}* but unfortunately enough I can not print it.

```
@Get('/:studentId')
getStudentById(
    @Param('studentId') studentId: string
){
    console.log(studentId);
    return "Get Student By Id: ${studentId}.";
}
```

Comment: this snippet is fine. What is the HTTP request that you're doing?? btw "I can not print it" won't help. Be more clear. The `console.log(studentId)` never runs our it always show `undefined`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

And this => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals